# THE JMF REGISTRY CANNOT CAPTURE PC CAM DEVICE 2..1.1E

Tags: java, jmf

i HAVE STARTED A NEW video STREAM PROJECT USING java LANGUAGE .I will put you in the scope of my two questions but keep know now that I will ask you about vedio capturing and detection ,not sending videos  .

1-I have downloaded the jmf studio and registry  . the problem in the jmf regestry .jfm registry cannot detect my pc cam .how can i detect it, or as i read in other words , where the jmf.properties can be put to run the registry well.

2- as i go forward to write the java code , i used this code to detect the cam:

```
   Vector<CaptureDeviceInfo> list = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList ( new 


       YUVFormat() );

        // Iterating list 
        for(CaptureDeviceInfo temp : list){
            // Checking whether the current device supports VfW
            // VfW = Video for Windows
            if(temp.getName().startsWith("vfw:")){

                            System.out.println("Found :                                
                "+temp.getName().substring(4));// Selecting the very first device that supports VfW
                cam = temp;
                System.out.println("Selected :  
          "+cam.getName().substring(4));
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Put it on work!...");
        // Getting the MediaLocator for Selected device.
        // MediaLocator describes the location of media content
        locator = cam.getLocator();///
```

this is just a snap shot, look now ,as no device can be detected the locator stay null, now my question is there a realation between the jmf registry and in general any project that will use this function to detect devices.  sorry for this long question .

note : as i try all the answers of this question which i have founded on the stack overflow or others with no success , i have been forced to ask it a gain .